Can I upgrade different Spring 5.x versions to a single 6.x version?
I want to upgrade my spring version to 6.1.0 for wildfly 28, but I found in my application  pom.xml, I see different version of spring related jar (e.g. 5.3.20, 5.2.2, 2.3.2.....), like the following:
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

is it needed to change all to version 6.1.7 like the following:
    <properties>
            <spring.version>6.1.7</spring.version>
    </properties>
    ......
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

or just change spring-core, spring-jcl is enough?

It's better to upgrade all Spring dependencies since they are compatible between each other, but be aware that not all Spring dependencies follow the same version pattern. In your example spring-ldap-core with group id org.springframework.ldap has his latest version in 3.2.x (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ldap/spring-ldap-core).
For all dependencies with group id org.springframework, you should be able to use a same maven version property as your example above.
If you want to follow spring dependency release date you can check Spring Release Calendar
